Simple ajax request with Vanilla JS keeps given 400 Bad Request
I am new to Ajax and hope someone can help me with the following.
I am trying to make simple ajax test in wordpress, but getting al the time a 400 Bad request. I am really wondering why this is not working. What am I doing wrong.
I am not able point to domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Can you please explain.
This is my html.
<form id="calc-form">
        <input type="number" id="numa" name="numa" placeholder="Enter number for a" required>
        <input type="number" id="numb" name="numb" placeholder="Enter number for b" required>
        <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>

<div id="result"></div>

This is my js file.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Attach a submit event listener to the form
    document.getElementById('calc-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        // Get the input values
        var numa = document.getElementById('numa').value;
        var numb = document.getElementById('numb').value;

        // Create a new AJAX request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        // Define what happens on successful data submission
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                // Display the result in the result div
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status); // Log any errors
            }
        };

        // Handle errors
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.error('Request failed'); // Log request failure
        };

        // Send the request with data
        xhr.send('action=calculate_numbers&numa=' + encodeURIComponent(numa) + '&numb=' + encodeURIComponent(numb));
    });
});

and this is my php
function calculate_numbers() {
    // Check if the values are set and valid
    if (isset($_GET['numa']) && isset($_GET['numb'])) {
        $numa = intval($_GET['numa']);
        $numb = intval($_GET['numb']);

        // Perform your calculation (e.g., addition)
        $result = $numa + $numb;

        // Return the result
        echo $result;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid input';
    }

    wp_die(); // Always include this at the end of your AJAX functions
}

add_action('wp_ajax_calculate_numbers', 'calculate_numbers'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calculate_numbers', 'calculate_numbers');

and functions.php
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the JavaScript file
    wp_enqueue_script('my-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mijntest.js', array(), null, true);

    // Localize script to pass AJAX URL to script
    wp_localize_script(
        'my-ajax-script',
        'my_ajax_obj', 
        array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');


Can you console.log( my_ajax_obj.ajax_url ) and make sure the value is coming through correctly?

Hi thank you for your answer. If I console.log()my_ajax_obj.ajax_url), it is showing the right endpoint. https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
What ever I try I am getting that issue, even a simple echo is not working.
So I guess I am making a mistake with the action.

usually you don't do get requests with ajax (do you realy want the result to be cached?), but in case you have to, you are doing it wrong, parameters should be in the url.  This is probably  why you get the 400 because wordpress gets the request but don't see any action in it. (you don't seem to send the numbers, but that comes after sending the action correctly)

You are a bit unspecific in terms of where you are trying to execute the request.
In case you want to GET data from an external point, you need to make sure that you are properly authenticated.
In case you want to GET data internally, you need to make sure you are including the correct "nonce" in your request.
What is the "nonce" ?
It is a "number, only used once".
It is a random number, generated by your system for your system in order to make sure that the request and the response are not manipulated.
UPDATE:
I've found an old snippet in my collection and thought you'd appreciate it, this used to be a working ajax request in a plugin:
<script>
$('#google_apps_enabled').on('change', function(){

        // Get user-id and setting
        var user_id = $('.btn-apps-settings').data('user-id');
        var setting = $('#google_apps_enabled').is(':checked') ? '1' : '0';
        var sidebar = $('#google-apps-sticky');

        // Fire our ajax request!
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            // Here we supply the endpoint url, as opposed to the action in the data object with the admin-ajax method
            url: apps_rest_object.apps_api_url + '/users/' + user_id,
            data: {'google_apps_enabled': setting},
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                // Here we set a header 'X-WP-Nonce' with the nonce as opposed to the nonce in the data object with admin-ajax
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', apps_rest_object.apps_api_nonce );
                $('#result').html(apps_rest_object.msg_loading).addClass('alert-warning');
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                if(response.google_apps_enabled == '1'){
                    $('#result').html(apps_rest_object.msg_enabled + '&nbsp;' + apps_rest_object.msg_reloading).removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-success');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                    }, 3000);
                    console.log(_x('Sidebar', 'company-text-domain'));
                } else if(response.google_apps_enabled == '0') {
                    $('#result').html(apps_rest_object.msg_disabled).removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-success');
                    sidebar.css('display', 'none');
                    console.log(_x('Sidebar', 'company-text-domain'));
                }
            },
            fail : function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#result').html(response.message).removeClass('alert-warning').addClass('alert-success');
            }
        });

    });

 <?php

// Best Post https://gopangolin.com/beyond-admin-ajax-using-wordpress-rest-api/
function rest_add_custom_user_endpoint() {
    // register_rest_field ('name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field(
        'user',
        'google_apps_enabled',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'user_meta_callback',
            'update_callback' => 'user_meta_update'
        )
    );
    register_rest_field(
        'user',
        'google_apps_sidebar_position',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'user_meta_callback',
            'update_callback' => 'user_meta_update'
        )
    );
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'rest_add_custom_user_endpoint');

function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
    return get_user_meta( $user['id'], $field_name, true );
}

//The callback handler for the endpoint
function user_meta_update( $value, $user, $field_name ) {
    return update_user_meta($user->ID, $field_name, $value);
}

?>


<?php

wp_register_script(
    'handle-unique-name',
    $dir . '/components/js/google-apps-frontend-actions.js',
    array('jquery'),
    NULL,
    true
);

wp_enqueue_script('handle-unique-name');


// Provide a global object to our JS file contaning our REST API 
// endpoint, and API nonce
// Nonce must be 'wp_rest' !
 wp_localize_script(
    // Script Handle
    'gac-google-apps-frontend-actions',
    // Js Object to internationalize
    'apps_rest_object',
    array(
        'apps_api_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
        'apps_api_url'   => site_url('/wp-json/wp/v2'),
        'msg_loading'   => __('Loading', 'company-text-domain'),
        'msg_enabled' => __('Google Apps enabled.', 'company-text-domain'),
        'msg_disabled' => __('Google Apps disabled.', 'company-text-domain'),
        'msg_reloading' => __('Reloading the page..', 'company-text-domain')
    )
);
?>

See this link for more information and this answer for a comprehensive overview:
WPSE Answer
WordPress Documentation Nonce

I have tried with nonce as well, nothing works, keeps given an bad request 400.
Tried this:
usually you don't do get requests with ajax (do you realy want the result to be cached?), but in case you have to, you are doing it wrong, parameters should be in the url.
Made sure one enqeuing is correct, places the url, before the open method.
So I am not sure why it is not working.
